# Algebra on $\binom{k+1}{i} = \binom{k+1}{0} + \binom{k+1}{1} + \cdots + \binom{k+1}{k} + \binom{k+1}{k+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, induction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Algebraic Proof that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}=2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18690/algebraic-proof-that-sum-limits-i-0n-binomni-2n)

I am trying to prove $\sum \limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} = 2^n$ by induction. I've been all over the net looking for a solution because I just don't understand how to go about it. I know the binomial theorem is involved somehow. I found [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20180209014153/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56597.html) which seems to explain it pretty well but I just cant wrap my head around the method.

Can you show me the algebra for this, I don't understand how they get were they are going. How do you algebra $\binom{k+1}{\textrm{anything}}$ into $\binom{k}{\textrm{anything}}$? I just can't make sense of it.

So assume that $\sum \binom{k}{i} = 2^k$.

$$\sum \binom{k+1}{i} = \binom{k+1}{0} +\binom{k+1}{1} + \cdots +\binom{k+1}{k} + \binom{k+1}{k+1} ,$$
the right side should boil down to $2^{n+1}$.

I'm sure after I'm shown this I will still have questions, but I'm just hoping it will make more sense. Thank you.

Comment: @msh210, Thanks for your improvements. But one note: it's somewhat standard these days to denote the binomial coefficient by `$\binom{n}{k}$` $\binom{n}{k}$ instead of $_n C_k$ or $C(n,k)$ or the like. So I made those changes.

Comment: @Srivatsan, I know it's standard among mathematicians, but I don't think it is in grade school, and I didn't want to include it in case the OP was unfamiliar with it. But I suppose your comment takes care of that concern.

Comment: Do you know the identity $\dbinom{k+1}i=\dbinom{k}i+\dbinom{k}{i-1}$? It allows you to reduce the upper number in the binomial coefficients by $1$. You can prove it either algebraically, by manipulating $\frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}+\frac{k!}{(i-1)!(k-i+1)!}$, or combinatorially.

Comment: @msh210 You raise a fair point :). In that case, it might be a good idea to make the edit anyway, and leave a comment explaining the notation.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/18690/).

Comment: @robjohn: It is, and both Mike Spivey’s and picakhu’s answers should be helpful to the OP, so I’ve voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint to get you started. Begin with the Binomial Expansion
\begin{align}
(x + y)^{n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^{k} y ^{n-k}.
\end{align}
Can you prove this identity by induction on $n$? If not, surely the base case $n = 1$ is easy to see and the following inductive hypothesis is not much harder to show:
\begin{align}
(x+y)^{n+1} = (x + y)(x + y)^{n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^{k + 1} y ^{n-k} + \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^{k} y ^{n-k + 1}
\end{align}
Now separate the terms, shift indices, unify the sums and use Pascal's Binomial Coefficient Identity (in the comments above) to finish the inductive proof.

To recover your sought-after identity, set $x = y = 1$.

Comment: It works, but it’s overkill (and a bit harder than necessary).

Comment: I strongly disagree with the assertion that "all that matters" about a given solution to a problem is whether the solution works!

Comment: If we are going to bring in the binomial theorem, we might as well just apply it: $2^k=(1+1)^k=\sum\limits_{i=0}^k1^{k-i}1^i\binom{k}{i}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}$