# A combinatorial equality $\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\right)^2=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom {2n}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

Prove or disprove that $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\right)^2=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom {2n}{k}$$
I cannot for the moment but it seems that it is true.

Comment: Simplify the summations. E.g., $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k$ is just the number of subsets of an $n$-element set, counted by their individual sizes. That leads to a trivial algebraic proof. A purely combinatorial proof is also possible; are you required to give one?

Comment: @Watson: No, it is not a duplicate of that question. That question contains information that can be used to answer this one, but it’s not the same question.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144256/sum-from-0-to-n-of-n-choose-i

Comment: I don't delette this post in deference to the good answers. How to harmonize one downvote and be eligible for bounty? I believed the question be interesting however I see now it is quite easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Expand $\;(1+1)^n\;$ and $\;(1+1)^{2n}$.

Comment: Incredible: I did not see this

Answer (score 2):

It’s working *much* harder than necessary, but just for fun here’s a completely combinatorial proof that does not require evaluating either summation explicitly. Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint $n$-element sets. The lefthand side is

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\right)^2=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{\ell=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{n}\ell=\sum_{0\le k,\ell\le n}\binom{n}k\binom{n}\ell\;.$$

For each pair $\langle k,\ell\rangle$ with $0\le k,\ell\le n$, $\binom{n}k$ can be interpreted as the number of $k$-element subsets of $A$, and $\binom{n}\ell$ as the number of $\ell$-element subsets of $B$. The term $\binom{n}k\binom{n}\ell$ therefore gives the number of ordered pairs $\langle X,Y\rangle$ such that $X$ is a $k$-element subset of $A$, and $Y$ is an $\ell$-element subset of $B$. When we sum these products over all pairs $\langle k,\ell\rangle$ with $0\le k,\ell\le n$, we must get the total number of ordered pairs $\langle X,Y\rangle$ such that $X\subseteq A$ and $Y\subseteq B$. In other words, we get $|\wp(A)\times\wp(B)|$.

Now look at the righthand side: $\binom{2n}k$ is the number of $k$-element subsets of the $2n$-element set $A\cup B$, and we’re summing over all of the possible values of $k$, so

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}k$$

is just the number of subsets of $A\cup B$, i.e., $|\wp(A\cup B)|$. We’re done if we can find a bijection between $\wp(A)\times\wp(B)$ and $\wp(A\cup B)$, and it’s not hard to check that the map

$$h:\wp(A\cup B)\to\wp(A)\times\wp(B):X\mapsto\langle X\cap A,X\cap B\rangle$$

is indeed such a bijection, with inverse

$$h^{-1}:\wp(A)\times\wp(B)\to\wp(A\cup B):\langle X,Y\rangle\mapsto X\cup Y\;.$$

Of course if one knows that an $n$-element set has $2^n$ subsets, the original identity simply reduces to $\left(2^n\right)^2=2^{2n}$ without further ado.

Comment: Brilliant!. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Piquito: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial theorem:
$$(\sum_{k-0}^n\binom{n}{k})^2=(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}1^{n-k}1^k)^2=((1+1)^n)^2=(1+1)^{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}1^{n-k}1^k$$

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you are after, but from a combinatorial point of view you even have:
$$ 
\left( \begin{matrix} 2n \\ m \end{matrix} \right)=
  \sum_{k+l=m,\ \ 0\leq k,l\leq n} 
\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ k\end{matrix} \right)
\left( \begin{matrix} n \\ l \end{matrix} \right)
$$
Which states that picking $m$ balls from a collection of $n$ red balls and $n$ white balls may be done by picking $k$ red ones and $l$ white ones. Summing over all $m$ (whence over all possibly $k$ and $l$) gives the stated result.

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you. (I must confess that I saw nothing of this).

Comment: You are welcome. Now I suppose the reply you give depends on the context of the problem, i.e. if you should argue using combinatorial reasoning or just plain algebra (like in other and simpler answers given here ).

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at it is the following:
$ {2n\choose m} = \sum_{l=0}^m {n\choose l}{n\choose m-l}$

This is true because the LHS is the number of ways of choosing $m$ objects out of $2n$. THis is the same as choosing $l$ objects from the first $n$, and $m-l$ objects from the last $n$ objects, summed over all values of $l \in \{0,1,\ldots,m\}$.

Now, summing this over all values of $m \in \{0,1,\ldots,2n\}$ gives the result.