# Summation of Combinations leads to $2^n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, summation, combinations

From trial and error I know that $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}= 2^n$$
Remember studying it. But can't prove it theoretically now. Can someone prove the above

Comment: ***Hint:*** Do you know that $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$?

Comment: You might want to look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519832/proving-by-induction-that-sum-k-0nn-choose-k-2n

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving by induction that $ \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} = 2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519832/proving-by-induction-that-sum-k-0nn-choose-k-2n)

Comment: Another variation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137727/evaluate-sum-limits-k-0n-binomnk-combinatorially

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} 1^k 1^{n-k} = (1+1)^n= 2^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Counting up every way you choose anything from $n$ things, is the same as for each thing you choose whether to include it or not.